# java.io.PrintStream display

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-io

I'm working on a java program using arrays and loops to create a table, however when the values print they are followed by "java.io.PrintStream@1909752" repeating over and over a number of times

The chunk of code causing the error is as follows, more specifically the "row +=" sections. Any help for how to get rid of the repeated part at the end would be appreciated.

```
for ( int i = starting; i <= ending; i+= 1){
    row += System.out.format("%6d" + ": ", i);

    for ( int j = 0; j <= 11; j+=1){
        double answer = i*octaveArray[j];
        row += System.out.format("%.0f ", answer );
    }
    System.out.printf(row);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: What do you think `row += System.out.format("%.0f ", answer );` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: I was using that to print the double values without decimal points/numbers following the decimals. The numbers all print correctly. Do you think that is a part of the problem?

Comment: What do you think the statement does though?

Comment: Appends the value of answer to the string?

Comment: So, no, that's not what it does. Why did you think so? Did you read the javadoc of `PrintStream#printf`? What do it do? What does it return?

Comment: Alright! I think I've fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [`PrintStream#format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

> Writes a formatted string to this output stream using the specified format string and arguments.

That means that `PrintStream#format()` will write the values to the output stream but you then append its `toString` representation which looks like `java.io.PrintStream@1909752` to the `row` variable which you then print out to the same output stream.

You should use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead if you wish to append the formatted result to a `String` variable.

Comment: I changed that section, but now there is still one iteration of the java.io.PrintStream at the beginning of the row, and one in the middle.